# If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and limits to $\infty$ ,$-\infty$ exist, prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}
> \> f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$ exist and are finite. Prove that
>   $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$

I used the sequence definition of uniform continuity; can someone say whether my proof is complete?

Let $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=l\;\;$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=l'$ .

Assume $x_n,y_n\;$are any two sequences in$\;\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(y_n-x_n)=0 $. Now the following four cases can occur.

Case I :  $\lim_{n\to \infty}(y_n,x_n)$ is finite; then $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=m$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(y_n)-f(x_n))=\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(m)-f(m))=0$.

Case II : $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n\to \infty;$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(y_n)-f(x_n))=\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(l)-f(l))=0$

In Case III and Case IV, similar arguments can be made for sequences tending to $-\infty;$ then in every case $\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(y_n)-f(x_n))=0$. Therefore $f$ is convergent on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: What if $x_n-y_n \to 0$ but neither $\{x_n\}$ nor $\{y_n\}$ is a convergent sequence?

Comment: Ohh I forgot the case thx

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and points $x_y,y_n$ such that $x_n-y_n \to 0$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| >\epsilon$ for all $n$. One of the following three possibilities holds:

a) $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_n'\}$ converging to some finite limit $l$.

b) $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_n'\}$ converging to $\infty$.

c) $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_n'\}$ converging to $-\infty$.

In all three cases the sequence $\{y_n'\}$ has the same property. Now we get a contradiction to above inequality by using continuity of $f$ at $l$ in case a), using the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and  is finite in case b) and the fact that  $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite in case c).

Comment: Thank you very much this was the proof I was looking for. A small error in line one it should be x_n